# Values are not being added to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am very new to PHP and Mysql. I have made a registeration form but the values being inputted are not being saved in my database. I don't know why. I am connected to the database. Could anyone give me some insight? By the way, I know you are going to say "Mysql" is deprecated. But I am just starting out and learning how all of this works. As soon as I have a thorough understanding of the processes I am going to change my code to Mysqli...

```
    <?php

    //form data
    $submit = strip_tags($_POST['submit']);
    $fname =  strip_tags($_POST['fname']);
    $lname = strip_tags($_POST['lname']);
    $usernamereg = strip_tags($_POST['usernamereg']);
    $passwordreg = strip_tags($_POST['passwordreg']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $emailcheck = strip_tags($_POST['emailcheck']);
    $date = date("Y-m-d");





    if($submit)
    {
//check for existence
        if($fname&&$lname&&$usernamereg&&$passwordreg&&$email&&$emailcheck)
        {   
    //encrypt password
    $password = md5($passwordreg);

      if(strlen($usernamereg)>25)
      {
        echo "Username must be 25 characters or less.";
      }
      else
      {
        //checks password length
        if(strlen($passwordreg)<6)
        {
            echo "Passwords must be atleast 6 characters long";
        }
        else
        {
            if($email!=$emailcheck)
            {
            echo "emails to not match";
            }
            else
            {

                //open database
                $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","clandestine");
                mysql_select_db("user_db"); //selects database

                $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$date','$fname','$lname','$usernamereg','$passwordreg','$email','$emailcheck'");
                echo "You have been registered!";

            }
        }

    }

}
else
    echo "Please fill in <b>all</b> fields!";
```

Comment: You used almost every bad programming practice available in this snippet of code.

Comment: how many columns you have in users table ? better write columns by their names

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` say?

Comment: @JohnConde is md5 worse then storing the password as plain text ? :-)

Comment: @Dagon tbh, it's almost on par.

Comment: Speaking of `par` - Classic "shoot one golf ball and hope it lands into all 18 holes, *at once.*"

Comment: Why is "just starting out" an excuse? You should learn the right way from the beginning -- unlearning bad habits will be harder.

Comment: It is not an excuse. Sorry. I just started programming and I am finding it very hard to learn because the explanations are so in depth. In depth meaning, I read the explanations for something, and I am still no closer to understanding because of all the terms/concepts I don't know. I was following a youtube tutorial for making a registration form. I am aware that I should not be using md5 but I just wanted to see how this works in hopes that it will help expand my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the columns in the INSERT query.

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (`randomField`, `date`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `email_check`) VALUES ('','$date','$fname','$lname','$usernamereg','$passwordreg','$email','$emailcheck'");
```

What is the first column supposed to be?

Have you done any sanity checking? (ie, printing test data to the screen at certain points in the code to make sure your IF statements are evaluating to true?

Additionally, try saving your INSERT query as a variable string:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO.............";
```

and then printing it to the screen. Copy and paste that query into PHPMyAdmin (if you have access to it) and see if there are any errors with your statement. PMA will tell you what errors there are, if any.

EDIT: Also, please don't ever MD5 a password or other highly sensitive data. Use a secure algorithm and salt the password. If you're unsure of what this all means:

refer to [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.bestpractice)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I have done sanity checking. All my if statements are working. I am going to try what you said right now.

Comment: Okay, I will check out that link right now. I am following an old youtube tutitorial on how to do this. I was just trying to get everything up and running before I started to change things. The first column is ID.

Comment: If the first column is ID, don't pass anything to it, as you are doing now.

Your ID field should be a PRIMARY KEY that is set to AUTO INCREMENT. Your statement shouldn't pass anything for that field.

mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (`date`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `email_check`) VALUES ('$date','$fname','$lname','$usernamereg','$passwordreg','$email','$emailcheck'");

Comment: Thank you for your response again. I have tried what you said, but none of my inputs from the form are being added to my database. I have checked to make sure my database's name is spelled correctly. Do I need to specify a table? I only have one table in the database.

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to specify a table.

Did you try making your insert query into a string and manually adding it your MySQL database via PHPMyAdmin (or similar)?

Comment: I have not yet because to be honest to you I do not know how to do that/what that means exactly. I am looking it up at the moment to prevent asking stupid questions...

Comment: Do this:

`$query = "INSERT INTO users (DATE_TABLE, FIRSTNAME_TABLE etc...) VALUES ("'.$date.'", "'.$fname.'", etc....)";

print $query;`

You will need to add your proper variables and table columns where I've got "etc.....".

Once the data is printed on the screen, see if it matches what you're expecting.

Comment: Okay, I just did what you said. When I print the query (mine is called $queryreg) nothing shows up..? Thanks for all of your input thus far.

Comment: Make sure you're not doing something like:

`$query = mysql_query("INSERT...."); print $query;`

That won't work. It needs to look like:

`$query = "INSERT INTO...."; print $query;`

Notice the removal of "mysql_query".

Answer (score 0):

What do you get if you do:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users 
(date, first_name, last_name, username, password, email, email_check) 
 VALUES 
('$date','$fname','$lname','$usernamereg','$passwordreg','$email','$emailcheck')";

mysql_query($query)or die('Error: <br />'.$query.'<br />'.mysql_error());
```

Note the removal of the backticks was just to simplify the code.  It's correct to leave them in but with no spaces etc in your column names it should work anyway.  Oh, and this is NOT good practice for production, of course.  Just really clear debug.

Comment: Adding that snippet of code produced "Error: Query was empty"

Comment: Since the query is empty and there wasn't a query echoed after the error, it would seem that the $query variable is empty.

Are there any typos?

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I completely retyped my if statements and it is working, so it must of been a syntax problem which I didn't spot which kept it from working.